# Getting nullpointerexception while using constructor

Tags: java, constructor, nullpointerexception

```
public class Author {
private int id;
private String name;
private String university;
private String department;
private String email;
private int article1;
private int article2;
private int article3;
private int article4;
private int article5;
//constructors and getter/setters are generated automatically, not adding to have space
}
```

This is my Author class. This class only has these attributes. Also I have a `readDaFile` class which is created to read `author.txt` and and create author objects.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class readAuthor {

private Scanner reader;
private String temp;
private String[] split;
public Author[] authorList;
private int dummyInt,dummyArticle1=0 ,dummyArticle2=0 ,dummyArticle3=0,dummyArticle4,dummyArticle5;
private int i=0;
private String name , university , department , email ;
public void tryOpeningOrDieTrying(){
 try{
     reader = new Scanner(new File("Author.txt"));
 }
 catch(Exception exo){
 System.out.println("Can not find file.");
 }
}
public void readDaFile(){

    while(reader.hasNext()){
        temp = reader.nextLine();
        split = temp.split(" ");

        name = "NOTGIVEN";
        university = "NOTGIVEN";
        department = "NOTGIVEN";
        email = "NOTGIVEN";
        dummyInt = 0;
        dummyArticle1 = 0;
        dummyArticle2 = 0;
        dummyArticle3 = 0;
        dummyArticle4 = 0;
        dummyArticle5 = 0;

        dummyInt = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
        if(split.length>2){ name = split[2]; }
        if(split.length>3){ university = split[3]; }
        if(split.length>4){ department = split[4]; }
        if(split.length>5){ email = split[5]; }
        if(split.length>6){ dummyArticle1 = Integer.parseInt(split[6]); }
        if(split.length>7){ dummyArticle2 = Integer.parseInt(split[7]); }
        if(split.length>8){ dummyArticle3 = Integer.parseInt(split[8]); }
        if(split.length>9){ dummyArticle4 = Integer.parseInt(split[9]); }
        if(split.length>10){ dummyArticle5 = Integer.parseInt(split[10]); }

        System.out.println(dummyInt+name+university+department+email+dummyArticle1+dummyArticle2+dummyArticle3+dummyArticle4+dummyArticle5);
        //authorList[i] = new Author(dummyInt,name,university,department,email,dummyArticle1,dummyArticle2,dummyArticle3,dummyArticle4,dummyArticle5);
 i++;
        //System.out.println(split[1]);
    //System.out.println(split.length);
    }
}
public void sealDaGates(){
reader.close();
}
}
```

Simply I'm reading lines first then split them into sub-elements to create author objects. But Author.txt might not give all author attributes.
For example :

```
 AUTHOR 100
 AUTHOR 101 Ruonan_Li MIT Computer_Science ruonan@mit.edu 1002001 1002009 1002004
```

To prevent sending null parameters to author constructor,I am initializing every attribute variable for every loop. I also checked initialized attribute variables by `printf`-ing them. They seem to work as intended. If I can't successfully read an attribute from txt , program sends `NOTGIVEN` or `0` to constructor. But still I am having `nullpointerexception` at line :

```
 authorList[i] = new Author(dummyInt,name,university,department,email,dummyArticle1,dummyArticle2,dummyArticle3,dummyArticle4,dummyArticle5);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In future, please put more effort into formatting the code in your question - and only posting *relevant* code. It would be entirely possible to show the same problem in about 10 short lines of code.

Comment: Do you understand what a NullPointerException is?

Comment: @djechlin-Apparently i do not .

Comment: @Jon-Will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 5):

You're never initializing `authorList`, so that's null. It's not the constructor call which is failing - it's the assignment into the array. You need:

```
authorList = new Author[...];
```

somewhere. Alternatively - and almost certainly preferrably - use a `List<Author>`, e.g.

```
private final List<Author> authorList = new ArrayList<Author>();
```

Comment: Thanks ,now it works as intended.I am not using ArrayList right now but will change it asap.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to initialize the `authorList` array. In the constructor, add this line `authorList = new Author[100];` and that should fix it. Change `100` to whatever number of elements you desire.